# Simplified Regex to remove dollar sign and anything after the decimal point in a string

Tags: regex, string

My goal is to remove everything after the decimal point in a string, including the decimal point with a regex.

**For example:**

$10,000.00 ==> 10,000

$500.05 ==> 500

This will work:

```
myString.replaceAll("[.][0-9]+$", "").replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```

but how can i do it with one regex? Thanks!

Comment: Your examples suggests that the strings of interest contain only a dollar amount but you have not said that is the case. Could the string be `I put  $500.00 on Bluenose to win`? If so, the title of your question suggests that should become `I put  $500`. If the string contains only a dollar amount, beginning `$`, you don't have to use a regex. If the string contains a period, return the string up to the index of the period minus 1, else return the entire string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use alternation:

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("^\\$|\\.\\d*$", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2qmHAT/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^\\$`: Match `$` at start
- `|`: OR
- `\\.\\d*$`: Match `.` followed by 0 or more digits before end

Answer (score 0):

Or simply use `gsub`:

```
gsub("\\$|\\..*", "", txt)
[1] "10,000" "500"
```